# RegEx for finding similar strings in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I got a variable that contains a list of users (as string). Some of these users have similar names. The only thing that's different is that they end with a "$" Symbol.

Example:

```
FRANK
FRANK$
```

I want to get a list of all these users with similar names. So if I had this list:

```
MAX
FRANK
FRANK$
HARRY
HARRY$
JULIA
TOM
```

I only want to get FRANK, FRANK$, HARRY and HARRY$ in the list and then check if the mail property of the AD user is not empty.

This is was I got so far, but the pattern doesn't fit:

```
$users = get-aduser -filter * | where givenname -ne $null | select -ExpandProperty name
select-string -InputObject $users -Pattern "[A-Z]+\$"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to find matching users:

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * | 
            Where-Object GivenName -ne $null |
                Group-Object @{e={$_.Name -replace '\$',''}} |
                    Where-Object Count -gt 1
```

You can access the actual user object again like this:

```
$users.Group
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern should be `[A-Z]+[$]?`, i.e. zero or one occurrence of the literal `$`.